# create visualization in Kibana of a geographical map with heat map showing latitude/longitude of transactions

Tags: kibana, visualization, elastic-cloud

I have an application that handles payment network transactions (from MasterCard via a third party issuer processor). For an approved auth we're able to ascertain (via a separate third party) the latitude and longitude of the merchant store where the transaction was initiated.

I'm logging the latitude and longitude to the stdout as follows:

```
Latitude: {latitude}
Longitude: {longitude}
```

Logs like this (and may others) get propagated through to ElasticSearch (in Elastic Cloud).

Using the latitude/longitude; how would I go about creating a visualization (in **Kibana**) of a geographical map with a heat map overlay that shows where the all transactions are coming from?

I'm thinking something like this (which is just an image from Google images):
[image]

or:

[image]

Ideally as you scroll in, the heat map precision would also get more detailed.

FWIW I have complete control over the log message in the source app, as well as various components in the telemetry pipeline where I could preform transformations (e.g. Logstash and Elastic ingest pipelines).

Answer (score 0):

The most performant solution would be to index latitude longitude data as [geo_point field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html).

Another, less performant solution, is to create a geo_point [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html).

Once your data is available as geo_point, you can use [Maps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/maps.html) to visualize the data on a map.